# How do I change the tab color in db dbeaver

Tags: dbeaver

I've looked everywhere in Preferences > User Interface > Appearance > Colors and Fonts
and it's not under the tabs filter text.  This is what I have now:
[image]

It would be really nice if the font and the selected tab color were a little farther apart.